# Bottom navigation bar doesnt get updated when logged in

Tags: flutter, dart

My goal is when someone log in the app, it will save user information with sharedpreferences,
start bottom navigation with new items in bottomnavigation bar which is not seen with not logged in user.
But somehow it gets error when after log in or log out.

The Navigation bar class

```
class NavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  NavigationBarState createState() => NavigationBarState();
}

class NavigationBarState extends State<NavigationBar> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> bottomItemsList = List();
  List<Widget> viewsList = List();

  // TODO: Husk array posisjon
  _viewContainer() async {
    List<Widget> loggedInList = [Home(), Info(), Admin(), Login(), TestLogIn()];
    List<Widget> notLoggedInList = [Home(), Info(), Login(), TestLogIn()];

    bool isLoggedIn = await UserPrefs.check("user");
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      viewsList.clear();
      viewsList.addAll(loggedInList);
      print("logged in");
    } else {
      viewsList.clear();
      viewsList.addAll(notLoggedInList);
    }
  }

  getNavigationBarItem() async {
    bool isLoggedIn = await UserPrefs.check("user");
    if (isLoggedIn) //if it is logged in
    {
      bottomItemsList.clear();
      bottomItemsList.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "Home", icon: Icon(Icons.home)));
      bottomItemsList.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "info", icon: Icon(Icons.info)));
      bottomItemsList.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "admin", icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings)));
      bottomItemsList.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "Profile", icon: Icon(Icons.account_box)));
      bottomItemsList.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "test", icon: Icon(Icons.new_releases_rounded)));
    } else {
      bottomItemsList.clear();
      bottomItemsList.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "Home", icon: Icon(Icons.home)));
      bottomItemsList.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "info", icon: Icon(Icons.info)));
      bottomItemsList.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "Profile", icon: Icon(Icons.account_box)));
      bottomItemsList.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(label: "test", icon: Icon(Icons.new_releases_rounded)));
    }
  }

  @override
    void initState() {
    getNavigationBarItem();
    _viewContainer();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void onTabTapped(int index) {
      setState(() {
        currentIndex = index;
      });
    }

    final colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: viewsList[currentIndex],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
          backgroundColor: colorScheme.surface,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
          //colorScheme.onSurface,
          unselectedItemColor: colorScheme.onSurface.withOpacity(.60),
          selectedLabelStyle: textTheme.caption,
          unselectedLabelStyle: textTheme.caption,
          onTap: onTabTapped,
          items: bottomItemsList),
    );
  }
}
```

Test log in class for testing purposes

```
class TestLogIn extends StatelessWidget {
  _toast(String text) {
    return Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: text,
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16,
    );
  }

  //Normal user test
  final User normalUser = new User(
      id: 1,
      name: "ola Nordmann",
      email: "ola Nordmann",
      password: "testtest",
      phonenumber: "12345678",
      roles: "USER");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Log in - NORMAL USER"),
              onPressed: () async {
                bool isLoggedIn = await UserPrefs.check("user");
                if (isLoggedIn) {
                  print(User.fromJson(await UserPrefs.read("user")));
                  _toast("You are already logged in!");
                } else {
                  await UserPrefs.save("user", normalUser);
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      '/NavigationBar', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                }
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text("LOG OUT"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await UserPrefs.remove("user");
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      '/NavigationBar', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```